Word or longer string meaning "to do something without really doing anything"
I'm looking for a term that encapsulates when someone does something without really doing anything. Take, for instance, when you are speaking to an unhelpful customer service representative, so to alleviate the tension they tell you they're going to transfer your call so you can speak to someone else. They've done something (transfer the call) but they also haven't really done much (i.e. help solve your issue). Is there a word for this? An intervention that is really a non-intervention?

In a comment below the asker mentioned that the verb dilatar is the term used in Spanish for this (although even there various other synonyms, phrases, and idioms also exist for it).

the noun for that is "administrator".

dilatory is a somewhat fancy term in English.

Perhaps something based on "action being nothing but smoke and mirrors"... Your CSR example is intended to give the customer the impression that their issue is being addressed when no such thing is happening.

@Fe2O3, if you believe that this is a reasonable answer to the question, and that it is sufficiently different from the already posted ones, you should post it as an answer, suitably elaborated.

@jsw29 The OP has provided a "use case", but the broader context and use can only be guessed. I don't see the allegory of "smoke and mirrors" as directly connected to the OP's example, so I submit this as merely a 'suggestion' - not an answer - that the OP may find 'workable'.

The answers of the indicated duplicate have different nuances which do not correspond to the answer the OP needs. Please reopen.

Go through the motions might be an accurate usage here. Collins explains
phrase

If you say that someone is going through the motions, you think they are only saying or doing something because it is expected of them without being interested, enthusiastic, or sympathetic.

Example from Vocabulary.com:

She isn't really working--she's just going through the motions.


Thank you for the suggestion. I like that it speaks to the kind of bureaucratic, spirit of the law vs. form of the law aspect I'm trying to capture. Thanks again!

You may be asking two different questions about doing something meaningless and doing the bare minimum.
If someone has achieved nothing and just wasted time, you could say they were spinning their wheels.

spin your wheels
idiom US informal
To waste time doing things that achieve nothing:
If we're just spinning our wheels, let us know and we'll quit.
Cambridge


spin one's wheels
US  Informal
To engage in fruitless activity
Collins

However, this wouldn't apply in the case of transferring a call. They have done something, although you could say it was the bare minimum or perfunctory.

perfunctory (adj.)
Characterized by routine or superficiality : mechanical
M-W


Yes, I think you're right - I'm looking for a single term that does two things: someone who simulates doing something but has really done nothing. Thank you for the suggestions!

This is a somewhat specialized usage, but the US Army commonly uses the term "shamming" to indicate the gentle art of not working while not getting caught at it. It is most commonly applied to SP4s, the usual rank between private and sergeant.It's not quite what you asked for, but I'm just throwing it out for entertainment.

Phone it in is the perfect idiom here—it's almost like a pun and oddly fitting for your customer service call transfer example. It's as if the only thing being transferred is the effort.
Wiktionary provides the defintion as:

(transitive, intransitive) As phone it in (idiomatic) To fulfill a responsibility with a minimum effort rather than the appropriate level of effort.


This sounds like a case of passing the buck:

pass the buck
1. (idiomatic, informal) To transfer responsibility or blame from oneself onto another; to absolve oneself of concern for a given
matter by claiming to lack authority or jurisdiction. Source:
Wiktionary

Here are some samples from the corpus:

All too often, poorly-run contact centers pass the buck from
agent to agent or keep customers on hold for extensive periods of
time 
*
Within eight months, more than 8 million people had seen the
humorous video, with “pass the buck” and “don’t ask me” lyrics
describing United’s customer service 
*  (And in case you want to see the
video . . .)


Thank you for the suggestion. As another commenter mentioned, although I'm looking for a term that encapsulates more than one thing, I definitely think passing the buck very aptly describes the passing on of responsibility that my example speaks to. Thanks again!

blow hot air
Much agitation, no practical result!

If you say that someone's claims or promises are just hot air, you are
criticizing them because they are made mainly to impress people and
have no real value or meaning.
source : Collins

Talk the talk, but not walk the walk

If you say that someone talks the talk but does not walk the walk, you
mean that they do not act in a way that agrees with the things they
say.
Source: Cambridge dictionary


Thank you for the suggestions!

It's a bit lengthy, and carries a notion of futility:

(May as well) rearrange the deck chairs on the Titanic.


(Edit addition of a suggestion for coining new allegory):

Like running in the "Wonderland Caucus Race".

Activity with no recognisable beginning or finish.
Achieving nothing from an expenditure of time and energy.
Going/getting nowhere, fast.

I just learned a new phrase, and it does wonderfully capture futility. Thanks for the suggestion!

Gosh, just when I hoped we'd heard the last of that ship.

@Lambie Are you kidding? It's the century's motherload of irony...

It's well said but I am so sick of the Titanic and its leftovers. :)

@Lambie "To forget the past is ..." The Challenger incident maps so well to the Titanic. "Failure of leadership" is the whole of human history. Maybe we'd be better off without "leaders"...

I don't think this applies to the situation in the question. These are not used to indicate that a person isn't even trying to do meaningful work.

"are not used to indicate that a person isn't even trying to do meaningful work" The double negative hurts my brain. As to applicability, the OP is at liberty to see things their own way. Thank you for your opinion...

Perhaps it may simply be 'unproductive' that speaks to doing something that does nothing.
Also,  'fruitless', or 'pointless'.
A grade of this concept may use,  'inefficient'.
Some people will do things to avoid something else and this is what I call,  'distraction actions', that may or may not fit your need.
I've heard this informally called,  'hem hawing', or 'pussyfooting' or 'jacking around'.
nugatory This is a good word.
He held that it authorized only those implied powers without which the enumerated powers would turn out to be "nugatory" or would come to nothing.
From Heritage.org
They're just as happy -- maybe happier -- with nugatory combinations of simple sentences and crude drawings.
From Slate Magazine
Criminal justice is just one more sphere -- along with health care, employment, lending, etc. -- in which race remains an immutable factor despite being nugatory as a measure of anything real.
Also,  someone may be,  'inept' for a particular task or situation.
Definitions from Oxford Languages
in·ept
adjective
having or showing no skill; clumsy.
"the inept handling of the threat"

Welcome to the site. With the exception of the term for masturbating, you have offered eight suggestions/verbs/adjectives/noun, not one answer that's best. Just a thought.

Language is subjective (in my opinion). There isn't a "best" word, necessarily, but if there were a definitive word that surpasses all others, surely one would need more context, such as who the communication is for, as example.  I assure you, the 'around' after the 'jacking' means wasting time doing nothing important, or causing delay. I've never heard it be anything to do with masterbating.

If the real focus here is to "alleviate the tension", then you are attempting to placate the person.

to soothe or mollify especially by concessions

MW

My understanding is that you are looking for a word for when the other person is taking some small action just for show that they know won't do any good, perhaps just to get rid of you. Sadly, I don't think we have a word for that. Some of the other suggestions are nice phrases to know, but their implication is effort in a futile cause, rather than feigned effort.

The verb "to turf" is slang (popularized by Samuel Shem's book House of God) and matches the usage in the example: to transfer a problem to someone else so you don't have to deal with it.
It's surprisingly hard to find a web reference.  This page is the best I could find, but it fails to capture the nuance from Shem's book. And it's patient-centric. I've seen the verb used to refer to any sort of transfer of a problem, especially when done through a thinly-veiled excuse for "not wanting to deal with it."

This behaviour smacks of  what people do when you say that they procrastinate or that they are dilatory.

(SOED) procrastinate 2 Defer action, delay; be dilatory.


(SOED) dilatory 1 Tending to cause delay; having the purpose of gaining time.


(Bush, the Detainees, and the Constitution: The Battle Over ... Howard Ball · 2007) The Supreme Court procrastinated when, on April 2, 2007, it denied certiorari on an expedited basis to review two petitions from Guantanamo detainees who challenged the constitutionality of the MCA.


Thank you for the suggestion. As another commenter mentioned, although I'm looking for a term that encapsulates more than one thing, I definitely think dilatory (dilatar is the verb used in Spanish) very aptly describes how the tactic I'm describing is used to buy time. Thanks again!

I would like to suggest "lotus eater".
°Noun Greek Mythology:a member of a people represented by Homer as living in a state of dreamy forgetfulness and idleness as a result of eating the fruit of the lotus plant:
Example:on arrival at the land of the lotus eaters, Odysseus sends out a reconnaissance party.
▪ a person who spends their time indulging in pleasure and luxury rather than dealing with practical concerns:
life as a lotus eater in sunny climes appears to be well and truly over. (Oxford dictionary)

This is rather old fashioned and its origins are obscure to the majority of English speakers. Moreover, it is inaccurate - "Lotus-eaters" did nothing and made no attempt to  appear as if they were doing something.
